# Arduino code for continuous rotation for 3 servos with Bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, servo

This code is working, any ideas?

Please check the code - Bluetooth is connecting but the servo motors are not varying with respect to the app sliders.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo1, myservo2, myservo3;

int bluetoothTx = 1;
int bluetoothRx = 0;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  myservo1.attach(9);
  myservo2.attach(10);
  myservo3.attach(11);

  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if (bluetooth.available() >= 2 )
  {
    unsigned int servopos = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int servopos1 = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int realservo = (servopos1 * 256) + servopos;
    Serial.println(realservo);

    if (realservo >= 1000 && realservo < 1360) {
      int servo1 = realservo;
      servo1 = map(servo1, 1000, 1360, 0, 360);
      myservo1.write(servo1);
      Serial.println("servo 1 ON");
      delay(10);
    }

    if (realservo >= 1000 && realservo < 1360) {
      int servo2 = realservo;
      servo2 = map(servo2, 1000, 1360, 0, 360);
      myservo2.write(servo2);
      Serial.println("servo 2 On");
      delay(10);
    }

    if (realservo >= 1000 && realservo < 1360) {
      int servo3 = realservo;
      servo3 = map(servo3, 1000, 1360, 0, 360);
      myservo3.write(servo3);
      Serial.println("servo 3 On");
      delay(10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: pins 0 and 1 are used by the arduino for serial communication. You cant use pins 0 & 1  and then use software serial as well.

Answer (score 1):

pins 0 and 1 are used by the arduino for serial communication. You cant use pins 0 & 1  and then use software serial as well.

If you do want to use softwareserial try this code https://gist.github.com/emil01/afedff4c3ba4625ebc75 Here i am using pins 2 & 3.

If you do not want to use software serial you can try this code https://gist.github.com/emil01/9a89800e383ec7f95b3f

In your code

```
  if (bluetooth.available() >= 2 )
  {
   unsigned int servopos = bluetooth.read();
   unsigned int servopos1 = bluetooth.read();
```

You are performing 2 consecutive read functions, this is not ideal as there can be data loss. A more ideal solution would be send a string with known string terminators and then parsing this string to get your required data.

For e.g. you could send

> S1:90\nS2:180\n

from this string you can clearly figure out the start and end of the string and accordingly manipulate the data for your need

Comment: then where do I connect my HC 05 tx rx? @evolutionizer

Comment: It says broken pipe error

Comment: the Tx pin of the bluetooth would go to pin 2 and Rx to pin 3

Comment: @AnitaB broken pipe error in your android log?

Comment: I changed the bluetooth tx rx pins to 14 and 15 and that did the work!!! BUT it moves clockwise and anticlockwise I also need to make it stop could you help me with it plz @evolutionizer

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @evolutionizer , you can't do SoftSerial + Serial (native) from pin 0 and pin 1. So the setup should be like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo1, myservo2, myservo3;

int bluetoothTx = 2;
int bluetoothRx = 3;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  myservo1.attach(9);
  myservo2.attach(10);
  myservo3.attach(11);

  //Setup USB serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}
```

As for the movement for the servo, more information about data sent from Android is needed.
If the app is sending continuous value instead of sending only if the value is changed, you can do this trick:

```
unsigned int lastpost;
void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if (bluetooth.available() >= 2 )
  {
    unsigned int servopos = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int servopos1 = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int realservo = (servopos1 * 256) + servopos;
    Serial.println(realservo);

    if (realservo >= 1000 && realservo < 1360 && realservo!=lastpost) {
      int servo1 = realservo;
      servo1 = map(servo1, 1000, 1360, 0, 360);
      myservo1.write(servo1);
      Serial.println("servo 1 ON");
      delay(10); //delay to wait servo rotate to desired position
      lastpost = realservo;
    }
...
  }
...
}
```